# What is the corresponding method for FTP PUT command in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

I have a requirement: "Please try using [FTP SERVER IP ADDRESS] as the FTP URL.  Please do a CD (change directory) to SFCD40DAT.  Then please do a PUT for FTPDRFTIN"

I am able to do this using Command Prompt:
[image]

How to achieve the same using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WebClient class and it's FileUpload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This way you can point to the address/folder directly and don't deal with low level commands.